# scipy.misc.factorial : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I followed this code on [scipy.misc.factorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.factorial.html).

However, I got this error.

```
if n < 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial
arr = np.array([3, 4, 5])
factorial(arr, exact=True)
```

While the following code has no error.

```
arr = np.array([3, 4, 5])
factorial(arr, exact=False)  # exact=False
```

Comment: This looks like a legit bug. What scipy version are you using? If it's one of the latest, do a search of the issue tracker on GitHub. If nothing similar pops up, file a report.

Comment: I'll take a look at the code in the morning.

Comment: AFAICT, this is working in scipy 0.18.1. -- which seems to be the latest released version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of scipy. I can reproduce the bug on my machine running 0.17.0. To see your version run

```
import scipy; print scipy.version.version
```

In version 0.18.0 the issue has been fixed, see [this commit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/f0a78a8f78f47706c31311dc052ea362bc6bf5da).

Before, `exact=True` was not supported for a list of numbers.